# iOS: Moving a uibutton by its tag outside of where it was generated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Is it possible? I have an array of buttons created in an void and I want to move one when a neighbouring one is called in the buttonTapped void. I have no trouble moving the button thats pressed because it is the sender, but I also need to move the one next to it and can't seem to get it to move. Each button in the array has a tag value so they're unique.

Thanks

Comment: could be please elaborate what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasonable intuitive assumption: you generated the buttons so that they are ordered in the array...

```
- (void)moveButton:(UIButton *)sender // whatever
{
    NSUInteger idx = [buttonArray indexOfObject:sender] + 1;
    UIButton *nextButton = idx < buttonArray.count ? [buttonArray objectAtIndex:idx] : nil;
    // do something with `nextButton`
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to want to recognize buttonArray... (happens to be what I called mine)

Comment: @NessyString Clarivoyance Experiments #1: maybe it's a local variable and not an instance variable.

Comment: You're the man, I allocated it properly in my h and it's all working now. Thanks

Comment: @NessyString No, you allocated it in one of the initialization methods of your class, in the header, it's *declared.* But I'm glad you got that working, you're welcome.